# How to efficiently add multiple columns to pandas data frame with values that depend on other dynamic columns

Tags: python, performance, pandas, dynamic

How can I use better solution instead of following codes? in big data set with lots of columns this code takes too much time

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'Jan':[10,20], 'Feb':[3,5],'Mar':[30,4],'Month':
                   [3,2],'Year':[2016,2016]})

#     Jan   Feb   Mar    Month  Year
# 0   10     3    30     3      2016
# 1   20     5    4      2      2016

df1['Antal_1']= np.nan
df1['Antal_2']= np.nan

for i in range(len(df)):
    if df['Yaer'][i]==2016:
        df['Antal_1'][i]=df.iloc[i,df['Month'][i]-1]
        df['Antal_2'][i]=df.iloc[i,df['Month'][i]-2]
    else:
        df['Antal_1'][i]=df.iloc[i,-1]
        df['Antal_2'][i]=df.iloc[i,-2]
df
#     Jan   Feb   Mar    Month  Year  Antal_1  Antal_2
# 0   10     3    30     3      2016    30       3
# 1   20     5    4      2      2016    5       20
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should see a marginal speed-up by using `df.apply` instead of iterating rows:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'Jan': [10, 20], 'Feb': [3, 5], 'Mar': [30, 4],
                   'Month': [3, 2],'Year': [2016, 2016]})

df = df[['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Month', 'Year']]

def calculator(row):
    m1 = row['Month']
    m2 = row.index.get_loc('Month')
    return (row[int(m1-1)], row[int(m1-2)]) if row['Year'] == 2016 \
           else (row[m2-1], row[m2-2])

df['Antal_1'], df['Antal_2'] = list(zip(*df.apply(calculator, axis=1)))

#    Jan  Feb  Mar  Month  Year  Antal_1  Antal_2
# 0   10    3   30      3  2016       30        3
# 1   20    5    4      2  2016        5       20
```

Comment: This is how I was thinking of doing it, after my mistake below, so have an upvote. @shoresh, [here](https://engineering.upside.com/a-beginners-guide-to-optimizing-pandas-code-for-speed-c09ef2c6a4d6) is a nice article about your options for improving speed in Pandas.

Comment: @Stev, thx. `df.apply` should really be a last resort (and, hopefully, avoid `iterrows` in any case). But I would be interested to see improvements to even this algorithm (which is still loopy). I'm sure the calculation can be vectorised via `pandas` shift functions.

Comment: I thought af first it could be written in a similar manner to my original attempt but I kept running into problems trying to get values from passing a Series of column names. I must be missing something obvious. How do I go from `pd.Series(df.columns[df['Month']-1])` to actually extracting the values from those columns?

Comment: @jp_data_analysis thanks a lot I tried your solution on my real data set which includes 5 years information and It worked very well , I voted your solution but unfortunately my profile is  less than 15 reputation and ...

Comment: @Stev ,thanks for sharing this article ,it was very useful!

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear to me what you want to do in the case of the year not being 2016, so I've made the value 100. Show an example and I can finish it. If it's just NaNs, then you can remove the first two lines from below.

```
df['Antal_1'] = 100
df['Antal_2'] = 100
df.loc[df['Year']==2016, 'Antal_1'] = df[df.columns[df.columns.get_loc("Month")-1]]
df.loc[df['Year']==2016, 'Antal_2'] = df[df.columns[df.columns.get_loc("Month")-2]]
```

Comment: Thanks Stev, My data set includes 12 months information + a column name Expiration month , I want to transfer 2 months before expire month in 2 new columns .in my example for row1 ,Expiration month is 3 then I need information of Mar and Feb but in row 2 Expiration month is 2 and I need Feb and Jan .

Comment: Does the code I showed work for you? I think it replicates what you are doing, I am just unsure what you are expecting if the year was not 2016.

Comment: it dosent work because it dosent care about value of Months . If the year was not 2016 I need to transfer information of last 2 months which in this sample is Mar , Feb